# Variables in java script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am developing an extension in which i need to generate URL of website differently.Here is the structure of my code i am using

```
<script>
var URL="";
function genURL(){
URL="xyz";
}
</script>
<body onload="genURL()">
<iframe id="if1" src="abc"></iframe>
</body>
<script>
document.getElementById("if1").src=URL;
</script>
```

above code is wrong as i cannot access element if1 in script code aboveits definitions and URL is not available in below script code.If we can access URL in Script code below , my problem will be solved. Or else is there a way to generate URL directly in  iframe .

Thanks

Comment: declare the URL variable as a global variable. `var URL = "xyz"`

Comment: You never seem to actually execute `genURL`, so `URL` won't be set...

Comment: @Aivan: the variable will be global because the `var` keyword is omitted. It won't work in IE, but I guess that doesn't really matter for a chrome extension. Still, the bigger problem is that `genURL` isn't called at all,

Comment: @David, you are right, he must have called it before executing his `document.getElementById()` function or as soon as the dom is loaded

Comment: The error i get on executing the code in chrome is  : 
<Uncaught ReferenceError: URL is not defined
(anonymous function)>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a function that assigns a value to `URL`, but you never call the function, so the code is created but not executed. There're a couple of ways to fix this. One is David's way. Another is to assign a value to URL outside of the function:

```
<script>
URL="xyz";
</script>

<iframe id="if1" src="abc"></iframe>
<script>
document.getElementById("if1").src=URL;
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

`URL` is not set at the time you're setting the iframes `src`. If you were to invoke `genURL` first, then your code would work. It would be far better, however, to design your code as such:

```
function getURL() {
    return "xyz";
};

...

document.getElementById('if1').src = getURL();
```